# String manipulation from command prompts wmic command

Tags: batch-file, cmd, split

The top part of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCBw3.png) text is the output I get from cmd command `wmic printer get name, portname`. Is there any way for me to add something to the command to get cmd to output the bottom string as output so that I get

> Printer: Port

for each of the printers in my list of printers with a comma seperating each of them?

Comment: I was having issues with this but found a similar issue which suggests using /format:csv, would that not make it easier?

Answer (score 0):

As per your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73482901/string-manipulation-from-command-prompts-wmic-command#comment129771853_73482901), here is a couple of basic examples which use the CSV format.

The first does not end each line with an additional trailing comma:

[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)

```bash
For /F "Tokens=1,* EOL=, Delims=," %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Printer Get Name^, PortName /Format:CSV 2^>NUL') Do @Echo(%H
```

[batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)

```bash
@For /F "Tokens=1,* EOL=, Delims=," %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Printer Get Name^, PortName /Format:CSV 2^>NUL') Do @Echo(%%H
```

If you wanted an additional trailing comma, then the following should do that:

[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)

```bash
For /F "Tokens=1,* EOL=, Delims=," %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Printer Get Name^, PortName /Format:CSV 2^>NUL') Do @For /F "Tokens=*" %I In ("%H") Do @Echo %I,
```

[batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)

```bash
@For /F "Tokens=1,* EOL=, Delims=," %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Printer Get Name^, PortName /Format:CSV 2^>NUL') Do @For /F "Tokens=*" %%I In ("%%H") Do @Echo %%I,
```

---

However neither of those examples provide output as shown in the image you should not have included in your question, ***(you should have submitted the text within a code box)***. To get something like that, the `/Format` type does not need to be CSV.

Here's a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) example, which uses `RAWXML` instead:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "i="
For /F "Tokens=1,3 Delims=<>" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe
 Printer Where "Name Is Not Null And PortName Is Not Null" Get Name^, PortName
 /Format:RawXML 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe
 /NRX "<VALUE>[^<][^<]*</VALUE>"') Do (If Not Defined i Echo Name: PortName
    Set /A "i=%%G" 2>NUL & SetLocal EnabledelayedExpansion
    For /F %%I In ('Set /A !i! %% 2') Do (EndLocal
        If %%I Equ 0 (Set /P "=: %%H, " 0<NUL) Else Set /P "=%%H" 0<NUL))
Echo(&Pause
```